# Error in cordova.js for windows 8 app

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-8, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I am porting my cordova hybrid app currently deployed on android platform to Windows 8/8.1.

My App uses Jquery2.0.0 / angularjs /jquery mobile and intel framework. I ported my app using VS2015 and it compiles fine.

But at runtime I am getting an error "prompt: undefinedin cordova.js".

I am new to this and any pointers on how to resolve this would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct Cordova.js file(s) for windows and that they are in the proper directory (should be your root web folder with your index.html page).

If you are not using the Cordova CLI to build the app, I would highly recommend it.  Adding the windows platform through the CLI gives you all of the cordova.js files you need when you build, you just need to make sure you reference them correctly (not in your scripts/js folder).

Also, make sure you're waiting for the "deviceready" event that cordova fires when it's ready to do work.